# oz-install failed with message "qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature"

Tags: kernel, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I was using `oz-install` to automize the generation of raw images, below are my config files.

corey.tdl

```
<template>
   <name>corey_x86_64</name>
   <description>CentOS 7 template</description>
   <os>
      <name>CentOS-7</name>
      <version>789</version>
      <arch>x86_64</arch>
      <install type='url'>
        <url>http://xx.xx.xx.xx/CentOS-7-x86_64.iso</url>
      </install>
   </os>
  <disk>
    <size>30</size>
  </disk>
</template>
```

corey.auto

```
echo 'Update packages'
yum update
```

The build command:

```
oz-install -d3 -a corey.auto -s "/home/corey/corey.img" -u corey.tdl -x corey.xml -t 3600
```

But it showed errors:

> libvirt.libvirtError: internal error: process exited while connecting
> to monitor: 2021-11-30T06:37:12.755723Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning:
> host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.svm [bit
> 2]  qemu: linux kernel too old to load a ram disk

I've read this [issue](https://github.com/GNS3/gns3-server/issues/1639) on Github, it might be the root cause somehow, but I don't know how to pass `-cpu host` to it while running with `oz-install`, and tried to set it in `.tdl` or `qemu.conf`, didn't work at all.

I was running on Ubuntu18.04, kernel 4.15.0-162-generic, libvirt 4.0.0, and QEMU version 2.11.1. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem doesn't matter to the Linux kernel but the syntax in `.tdl` file.

After I replaced `install type='url'` with `install type='iso'`, it worked.

Here is the correct answer to me:

```
<install type='iso'>
  <iso>file:///home/corey/CentOS-7-x86_64.iso</iso>
</install>
```